# Why AngularJS data binding is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Playing with some AngularJS and a very simple example is not working - like Angular isn't loading. In the example I have a simple data binding test where I'm just using {{}} to print out a hardcoded string. But all I get are the braces and the string inside of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head >
    <title >Data Binding</title >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="../libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="main.css"
      rel="stylesheet" >
</head >

<body >

<div class="container" >
    {{ 'dummy text' }}    <<== Uninterpreted Angular
</div >

<script src="../libs/angular/angular.min.js" ></script >
</body >
</html >
```

The HTML validates, but I can't see why it won't execute properly. It's probably one of those "everyone knows that" type of thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  just replaced your angular reference with CDN and it works fine. Here is the code snippet. May be your include directory is wrong for angular or your angular file is corrupted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head >
    <title >Data Binding</title >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="../libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="main.css"
      rel="stylesheet" >
</head >

<body >

<div class="container" >
    {{ 1+1 }}  
</div >

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js" ></script >
</body >
</html >
```

Comment: The location of the angular file is correct, but for some reason it won't load/use it. I'll try and download a new copy, but putting in a CDN did work. Thanks.

Comment: When I put the angular.min.js file into a `js` subdirectory, it worked. I think descending a directory tree is fine, but backing up the tree is not allowed.